# Wave Equation and Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, harmonic-functions, wave-equation

I was given a guitar string of length 1 with fixed endpoints. My $f(x)$ is $2x$ if $(x \le 0.5)$ and $-2x+2$ if $(x \gt 0.5)$. My initial velocity is 0. $f(x)$ is the initial position

I was first asked to find first 3 coefficients in sine Fourier series. By doing $a_k = \frac{2}{l} \int_0^1 f(x)sin(\frac{\pi kx}{l})dx$, I got that $a_1 = \frac{8}{\pi^2}$, $a_2 = 0$, and $a_3 = -\frac{8}{9\pi^2}$.

Now, the question asks for solution of this initial boundary problem. Basically, I have $u_t(x,0) = 0$ and $u(0,t) = u(1,t) = 0$. I learned that the general solution looks like the following

$u(x,t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} sin(\frac{\pi kx}{l})(a_k sin(\frac{\pi kx}{l}) + b_k cos(\frac{\pi kx}{l}))$.

Now, I know $l=1$ and I can simply substitute 1,2, and 3 to $k$. I already have corresponding $a_k$ to this. However, I am not sure if there is a $b_k$. I think that all $b_k = 0$ leading me to conclude that $u$ only has $sin$ in it. However, I am not sure how to arrive at the solution. Could someone help? Thank you.

Comment: What is the full problem? You only mention a physical situation with some of the data.

Comment: What exactly do you think is missing? This is pretty much all I got from the problem. I did add that $f(x)$ describes the initial position

Comment: I see, perhaps you could edit your post with your formulation of the initial value problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The
>   $\ds{\mrm{u}_{xx}\pars{x,t} - \mrm{u}_{tt}\pars{x,t} = 0}$ general solution is given by

\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{n\pi x}
\\[2mm]
\mbox{such that} &
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\braces{\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}\bracks{-n^{2}\pi^{2}\sin\pars{n\pi x}}
- \ddot{\mrm{a}}_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{n\pi x}}
\\[2mm] \implies 
0 & = \bracks{\totald[2]{}{t} + \pars{n\pi}^{2}}\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{t}
\end{align}

---

$$
\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0}\cos\pars{n\pi t} +
\dot{\mrm{a}}_{n}\pars{0}
{\sin\pars{n\pi t} \over n\pi}}\sin\pars{n\pi x}}
\\
\ds{\mrm{u}_{t}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\dot{\mrm{a}}_{n}\pars{0}\sin\pars{n\pi x} \implies
\dot{\mrm{a}}_{n}\pars{0} = 0}
\\
\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0}\sin\pars{n\pi x} \implies
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0} = 2\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{u}\pars{x,0}
\sin\pars{n\pi x}\dd x}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\mrm{a}_{n}\pars{0} & =
2\int_{0}^{1/2}2x\sin\pars{n\pi x}\,\dd x +
2\int_{1/2}^{1}\pars{2 - 2x}\sin\pars{n\pi x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{8\sin\pars{n\pi/2} \over n^{2}\pi^{2}} =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{0} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n}\ \mbox{is}\ even
\\
\ds{8\pars{-1}^{\pars{n - 1}/2} \over n^{2}\pi^{2}}
& \mbox{if} & \ds{n}\ \mbox{is}\ odd
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} =
{8 \over \pi^{2}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}\,
\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi x}
\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\pi t}}
$$

Comment: I am sorry. Could you explain where did you get the cosine?